Email template is responsive in almost every client except a few. How do I fix this?
We have an HTML/CSS email template we've built that is fully responsive in the browser, and in almost all desktop email clients and mobile email clients except for Polymail and Thunderbird. We cannot figure out what is causing them to not be responsive in these two email clients but it is responsive in all the others. Any one have any tips?
Here is the code we are using to generate the template. Please note this template is used on both web and for email, so it contains some stuff that is not particularly for email.
We've checked all image sizing and that does not appear to be the problem.
Email Template on Codepen
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
   <head>
      <title>Digest</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, date=no, address=no, email=no">
      <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
      <meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
      <meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light dark">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
     <style type="text/css">:root {
    color-scheme: light dark;
    supported-color-schemes: light dark
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100% !important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important
}

img {
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: 0 !important
}

p {
    Margin: 0 !important;
    Padding: 0 !important
}

.ExternalClass * {
    line-height: 100%
}

.em_defaultlink a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none
}

.em_defaultlink1 a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: underline
}

.em_g_img+div {
    display: none
}

.em_full_img img {
    border-radius: 8px
}

.em_full_img1 img {
    border-radius: 6px
}

.rss_content * {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: unset;
    margin: unset
}

.rss_content img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important
}

.rss_content p {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important
}

.rss_content p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important
}

.rss_content p a {
    color: #fcad03 !important
}

.reddit_content * {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: unset;
    margin: unset
}

.reddit_content img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto !important
}

.reddit_content p {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important
}

.reddit_content p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important
}

.reddit_content p a {
    color: #fcad03 !important
}

.source_message_text_wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left
}

.source_message_text {
    margin-top: 18px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #e5e2e2;
    opacity: .5;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center
}

#MessageViewBody a,
a[x-apple-data-detectors],
u+.em_body a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit
}

@media only screen and (max-width:667px) {
    .em_main_table {
        width: 100% !important
    }

    .em_wrapper {
        width: 100% !important
    }

    .em_hide {
        display: none !important
    }

    .em_full_img img {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important
    }

    .em_full_img1 img {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto !important;
        max-width: none !important
    }

    .em_center {
        text-align: center !important
    }

    .em_side10 {
        width: 10px !important
    }

    .em_aside10 {
        padding: 0 10px !important
    }

    .em_side15 {
        width: 15px !important
    }

    .em_aside15 {
        padding: 0 15px !important
    }

    .em_ptop {
        padding-top: 20px !important
    }

    .em_pbottom {
        padding-bottom: 20px !important
    }

    .em_h20 {
        height: 20px !important;
        font-size: 1px !important;
        line-height: 1px !important
    }

    .em_h30 {
        height: 30px !important
    }

    .em_mob_block {
        display: block !important
    }

    .em_hauto {
        height: auto !important
    }

    .em_clear {
        clear: both !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        display: block !important
    }

    u+.em_body .em_full_wrap {
        width: 100% !important;
        width: 100vw !important
    }

    .em_pr0 {
        padding-right: 0 !important
    }

    .em_pad1 {
        padding: 20px 15px !important
    }

    .em_pad2 {
        padding: 0 15px !important
    }

    .em_pad3 {
        padding: 20px 15px !important
    }

    .em_pad4 {
        padding: 15px 15px 0 !important
    }

    .em_pt1 {
        padding-top: 8px !important
    }

    .em_pt2 {
        padding-top: 24px !important
    }

    .em_pt5 {
        padding-top: 5px !important
    }

    .em_h40 {
        height: 35px !important
    }

    .em_h0 {
        height: 0 !important
    }

    .em_h10 {
        height: 8px !important
    }

    .em_h5 {
        height: 5px !important
    }

    .em_w5 {
        width: 5px !important
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:374px) {
    .em_hide1 {
        display: none !important
    }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme:dark) {
    .em_body {
        background-color: #111 !important
    }

    .em_module {
        background-color: #111 !important
    }

    .em_txt_white {
        color: #fff !important
    }

    .em_txt_white a {
        color: #fff !important
    }

    .em_txt_dark {
        color: #000 !important
    }

    .em_txt_dark a {
        color: #000 !important
    }

    .em_dark {
        background-color: #000 !important
    }

    .em_light {
        background-color: #fefefe !important;
        border-radius: 8px !important
    }

    .em_light01 {
        background-color: #2a2a2a !important
    }

    .em_invert_img img {
        filter: invert(1) !important
    }
}

</style>
   </head>


If you are making a email template, you may have to use outdated elements like nested <table> tags and the <center> tag etc etc ..  Some email clients (I'm looking at you Outlook) aren't great at rendering HTML written using current standards.

I find this a very useful website: https://www.caniemail.com

This is too difficult to answer without knowing more information. If you remove the styles, since the code is desktop-first, it still shows multiple columns and looks fine on desktops. So what do you mean by it being not responsive on a desktop client like Thunderbird exactly? If you mean that you can't change the view to mobile, that's not something I would expect customers would need. Thunderbird doesn't support @media, so I gather that's why this behaviour is occurring https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-media/

it works fine in all clients except polymail as far as I can tell on mobile. Problem is polymail is my default client so trying to figure out what the issue is here.
here is a screenshot to show what I mean:
Polymail mobile app - not responsive: https://i.imgur.com/qNRW7dT.png
Every other mobile email client - responsive: https://i.imgur.com/FCCBtqM.png
